# Как перезагрузить reCAPTCHA

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

Как можно перезагрузить reCAPTCHA через js?

Пробовал так:

```
var rc = grecaptcha.getResponse();
            if(rc == "" || pass == "" || login == ""){
                var div = document.querySelector("#div");
                div.innerHTML = "Вы некорректно ввели логин <br> или пароль или не прошли проверку reCAPTCHA";
                return false;
            }else{
                $.post("auth.php", {'login': login, 'password': pass, 'remember': remember},
                    function(data){
                    alert(data);
                        if(data == "false"){
                            var div = document.querySelector("#div");
                            div.innerHTML = "Неверный логин или пароль";
                            grecaptcha.reset();
                        }else if(data == "true"){
                            //null
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Но `grecaptcha.reset();` не работает почему то.  Может что неправильно?